# window.open window.write window.print window.close

Tags: javascript

UPDATE: After doing some digging and further research I have found that this is actually unintended behavior.  Here is a discussion about this on the chrome release updates https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2018/03/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html

I am still open to any sort of JS workaround to get this to work though.

I had some legacy code that worked fine using the following:

```
var printandclose = function(){
    var w = window.open();
    w.document.write(`<div>ajaxdatafromsomewhereelse</div>`)
    w.print();
    w.close();
}
printandclose();
```

But after a recent Chrome update to version 64+ this no longer seems to work.  The tab is immediately closed, the spooler briefly receives something, but then nothing prints as if the data being sent by chrome is bad or corrupt.

The above code works fine in other browsers, such as firefox or edge, but not chrome.  What can I do to work around this?

Comment: This is working for me on Windows 7, Chrome 65.0.3325.146 (and 64 before it just updated itself). Are you getting errors in the console, likely access denied if anything

Comment: No I am getting no errors in chrome, and nothing occurs other than the tab closes that I can see.  Am really not sure what to do.

Comment: Also, I am on windows 10, not 7, if that matters.

Comment: Chrome 64 + Mac ... opens a print dialogue in a new tab.

Comment: It opens the dialogue fine, and will even load the stuff in the dialogue, but when printing, NOTHING happens.  I am asking specifically for you to try actually printing something out using the above in chrome 64+ with windows 10.  For some reason, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) seems to resolve printing issue for me.